# Can't locate Windows 10 program (BurnInTest_Autorun) in "Startup Apps"

Tags: windows, windows-10

I bought a new Windows 10 PC and only installed a couple of programs (Bitdefender and Privacy Eraser). I then noticed "BurnInTest_Autorun" in my "Startup Apps". Some research indicated this is a program often used by PC suppliers to test their machines. So I assume the company I bought this PC from installed it.

However, I am unable to locate the program anywhere.  I've looked in "Program Files" etc, done a keyword search, nothing. In "Task Manager" I can see it in the "Startup" tab, but the "Publisher" field is blank. Right-clicking doesn't allow me to see the location of the file. I went to "Add or remove programs" and it wasn't there.

I want to find and delete this thing, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Install [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/) and see in it can find `BurnInTest`.

Comment: Not here on my machines.  Scan for viruses with Windows Defender. Try to remember some app you installed.

Comment: Also look in Settings, Apps to see if something was installed via Apps.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns